# CEF not saving local storage data, when the application is shutdown

Tags: chromium-embedded

I have created an application using JCEF. My application is using the localstorage for saving its settings. The problem I'm seeing, is that each time the application is closed, and restarted, all the data in the localstorage is discarded. I have tested using the CEFSimple app from multiple versions, (see my ticket here https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/java-cef/issues/386/localstorage-is-empty-after-application), and the same problem is reproduced. So I'm suspecting a missing setting somewhere. Does anybody know, what is missing or can confirm this is a bug ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I identified the root cause for this issue: the problem happens when setting a relative path in `cache_path` inside `CefSettings`. When I changed to an absolute path, the issue disapparead.